# steam my desktop over Network by VideoLAN

Tags: vlc, desktop, live, steam

I am trying to steam my desktop from windows machine ( client ) to my server (linux) ....over my network

this is the command i used in my client side ( windows )  :

```
vlc.exe screen:// :screen-fps=30 :screen-caching=100 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,vb=4096,acodec=mpga,ab=256,scale=1,width=1280,height=800‌​}:standard{access=http, mux=ts, dst=192.168.1.5:8080}'
```

on my linux i try to open :
192.168.1.5:8080 from my web but it does not work

> linux ip : 192.168.1.5
>
> win ip   : 192.168.1.30

how i can do that ??

Comment: For `Linux` machine you have local address and for `Windows` public address. Are you sure that you connected to the same network? Also, is it possible to go out of `NAT` for `Linux` machine?

Comment: sorry i forget 2 .... yes they are in same network i will modify it